# (UWP) Referencing the parent page from a navigated frame

Tags: navigation, window, uwp, frame

I have two pages, One and Two. Page One contains a hamburger menu as well as some other objects intended to be reused across multiple pages. Within Page One, there is a frame named `ContentFrame`, that navigates to other pages using `ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageTwo), this)`. Once navigated, I can reference the contents that I want to modify within Page Two, but if I wanted to reference objects present in Page One from Page Two, how would I do that?

Image of Visual Tree:

[image]

Specifically, I am trying to reference `errorPopup` from Page Two. I have tried using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`, but after I get the parent page (Page One), I am not able to edit and of its children. What is the best way to do this in UWP since Window. GetWindow is not available?

Comment: Ehhhh no. No no no no no. Please don't nest a page in another page...

Comment: What would be the better method then? I want to reuse the hamburger button and top frame across all of the pages that I'm navigating to.

Comment: Then put the control in a separate file and reference it in each page

Comment: What you're doing is similar to putting a window in a window

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way:

I created a class in Page One with fields for each item that I wanted to create:

```
public class MainPageControlAccessor
{
    public static Popup errorPopup;
}
```

and then on Page Two, you reference using

```
MainPageControlAccessor.errorPopup.PROPERTY_TO_MANIPULATE
```

It was way simpler than I thought lol

Comment: Getting "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" with this (setting image source)